# Making an HTTP Request When there is a Javascript

Tags: javascript, perl, httprequest

I would like to generate an http request.  I believe the following code works except for the current my $uri line because I tried it with the google website (uncomment out that line and comment out the current uri line).  Then I tried it with a site of interest and it fails.  I believe it fails, in part, because there is a javascript on the webpage.  I say it fails because in the last line, it does not satisfy the if statement, and instead, it dies.  I would have considered it a success if it did not enter that if statement.  Any suggestion on how to get this going?

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use LWP::UserAgent;
 use URI::Escape;

 my $uri = "https://familysearch.org/search/collection/results#count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3ALester%20%2Bsurname%3AYoungblood%20%2Bevent_place_level_1%3AGeorgia%20%2Bevent_place_level_2%3AWhitfield%20%2Bevent_place_level_3%3ACarbondale%20%2Bgender%3AM&collection_id=2000219";
#my $uri = "https://www.google.com";

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'GET', $uri );
$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $lwp->request($req);
if ( not $res->is_success ) { warn "Bad response :("; sleep(1); die; }
```

Comment: If I remove the call to `$req->header()` it works just fine -- or at least, is_success is true, and the error message no longer prints.

Comment: Right. you definitely shouldn't do `GET` request with `Content-Type` header. In this case the server you tried to request returns `500 Internal Server Error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another URL:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $json_uri =
"https://familysearch.org/search/records?count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3ALester%20%2Bsurname%3AYoungblood%20%2Bevent_place_level_1%3AGeorgia%20%2Bevent_place_level_2%3AWhitfield%20%2Bevent_place_level_3%3ACarbondale%20%2Bgender%3AM&collection_id=2000219";

my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'GET', $json_uri );

$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );

my $res = $lwp->request($req);

if ( not $res->is_success ) { warn "Bad response :("; sleep(1); die; }
```